# Rails 4.1 Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, svg

Trying to add a background image to my rails app  `background: url('../img/dot-matrix.svg') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;` but getting error `Invalid CSS after "...ath 'dot-matrix": expected ")", was ".svg' %>') 50% ..."

Have copied the dot-matrix.svg file under assets/images directory

Gone to my css.scss file and changed it to  `background: url('<%= asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;`so it shows this in my css.scss file

```
.dotmatrix {
    background: url('<%= asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 50%;
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

but getting error `Invalid CSS after "...ath 'dot-matrix": expected ")", was ".svg' %>') 50% ..."`

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Oc</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to escape single quotes. Try to use this

```
background: url('<%= asset_path "dot-matrix.svg" %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
```